# ffmpeg/ffprobe to produce a numeric array output

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, ffprobe

i have been using [this npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/waveform-util): to create a waveform numeric output such as this below:

[0,0.0062,0.0688,0.2524,0.2691,0.2645,0.1594,0.1397,0.1672

however, this module may not be supported very well and has not been maintained for a couple of years now. the module describes itself as a "tiny wrapper around ffprobe".

my question - what would the ffmpeg/ffprobe command line look like to produce a numeric array output?

thank you very much.

Comment: i should have mentioned this: i am not knowledgeable enough with node.js to dig into the source code and determine where the call to ffmpeg/ffprobe is happening and attempt to dissect it.

Comment: What does the array represent?

Comment: i think the array is decimal values of decibels but that is just a guess.  when i feed the array into wavesurfer player i get a good waveform.

Comment: i found another one that works and is more current:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/waveform-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ npm install waveform-util 
$ cd node_modules\waveform-util
$ cat package.json | grep depend -A 10 | head -4
```

We see there is `node-ffprobe` and `pcm` dependency.

```
$ cd lib
$ vim waveform.js
```

There are two exports. `audio_data` using `ffprobe` and `generate_peaks` using `pcm`. Lets check first `node-ffprobe`.

```
$ cd ..\node-ffprobe      # I'm on windows - hence backslashes
$ grep -Rni spawn .       # or exec, but exec returned nothing useful
```

We see there is `spawn` used in `./lib/ffprobe.js` L84

```
$ head -84 lib/ffprobe.js | tail -1     # just print line 84

C:\del\express-drive\node_modules\node-ffprobe>head -84 lib/ffprobe.js | tail -1
            var proc = spawn('ffprobe', ['-show_streams', '-show_format', '-loglevel', 'warning', file]),
```

So this is bottleneck where `ffprobe` command is run. By putting: `console.log(file)` or `console.log('ffprobe', ['-show_streams', '-show_format', '-loglevel', 'warning', file].join(' '));` before that line we could get specific command used to run when running an app.

You haven't posted example you are using, so I have to go back to waveform-util.

```
$ cd ..\waveform-util
$ grep -Rni ffprobe .
```

So `lib\waveform.js` L122 uses `audio_path` as first parameter which is passed to `node-ffmpeg`. I guess that would be the `file` as last argument for `spawn`. But this does not answer your question.

If we go back and take a look at `waveform-util\lib\waveform.js:audio_data` it is using `ffprobe` to export only basic info about audio data file but not the *generate audio stream from ffmpeg command* you want.

(`head` `tail` thing is just to print range of lines from file)

## PCM

Let's check `pcm`.

`generate_peaks` from `waveform-util\lib\waveform.js` uses `pcm` module. I'll shorten this one.

```
$ (node_modules) cd pcm
$ grep -Rni -A 2 spawn .
```

Second result shows:

```
./lib/pcm.js:33:  var ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i',filename,'-f','s16le','-ac',channels,
./lib/pcm.js-34-    '-acodec','pcm_s16le','-ar',sampleRate,'-y','pipe:1']);
./lib/pcm.js-35-
```

You can generate command same as above; put this before/after `spawn` and it will print you the command it is running:

```
console.log('ffmpeg', ['-i',filename,'-f','s16le','-ac',channels,'-acodec','pcm_s16le','-ar',sampleRate,'-y','pipe:1'].join(' '));
```

And when running anything through `waveform-util` you'll see command that is producing whatever `pcm` needs. Note that `pcm` does extra manipulation on `.on('data', ...` handler below `spawn` call so it may not be same output, but the you'll capture the command.

Comment: thanks - i tried to run a command based on what you managed to discover and the command looked like this:  "ffmpeg -i   /test.opus  -f s16le -ac 1 -acodec   pcm_s16le  -y pipe:1  >  result.txt"  but the result.txt file contained raw data, not a numeric array.

Comment: i should think there would be a couple of simple CLI switches to create a numeric, and it would be covered in the ffmpeg instructions.

Comment: @edwardsmarkf hello. did you find a way to get the numeric array in the end?

Comment: Upd:  I had to use python to decode the raw data with the help from here: https://superuser.com/questions/1481748/ffmpeg-encode-audio-as-list-of-samples

Comment: sorry its been too long and i cannot remember. i think we switched over to katspaugh-wavesurfer about that point so i no longer needed this.